# Concat 2 TFS WorkItemCollections?

Tags: c#, tfs

I am pulling TFS workitems for different date ranges and would like to concat these workitemcollections. There is no `.AddRange()` or `.Add()` method available.

How can I concat WorkItemCollections?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: while (queryDate <= endDate)
                {
                    WorkItemCollection QueryResults = GetData(WorkItemStore, queryDate, queryDate.AddDays(5)); queryDate = queryDate.AddDays(5) }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you convert each WorkItemCollection to a List with .ToList then you can use linq to join them.